Torah term for putting others first?
Pretty self-explanatory. Is there any Torah term or phrase that refers to the ethical act of "Putting Others First"?

שלי שלך ושלך שלך, חסיד

Being Mevatter?

A word adopted from yiddish פירגן, לפרגן, פרגון?

Edited the question to make it on topic, to avoid closure.

To be mevatter means to give way, yield, concede, forgo, or waive.  It is related to the root יתר, which means to leave over, and to the word יותר (more).  An examplar in the Torah of this behavior is Rachel Imenu.  Yaakov agreed to work for Lavan to marry his daughter Rachel, but Lavan gave him her sister Leah instead.  The Torah says that the next morning Yaakov realized it was Leah.  Rashi says Yaakov hadn't realized the previous night because he had given signs to Rachel but when she saw they were giving him Leah she was afraid her sister would be embarrassed, so she gave those signs to Leah.  (Rachel was rewarded for this; cf. Rashi/Radak on Jeremiah 31:15.) Although I feel this is an example of being mevatter, I didn’t see that word actually used there.  The word mevatter can also be used in a negative context, as in Mishna Sanhedrin 11:5 “one who disregards (the words of a prophet).”

I think mevater is a fairly modern term. Personally it rubs me the wrong way, because it sounds begrudging instead of gracious.

Rachel was rewarded: Talmud Megilla 13b https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13b.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi. This quality was interpretated as צְנִיעוּת. Also Bava Basra 123a https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.123a.18?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi

The word מוותר is used in Bereshis Rabba 49:9 https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.49.9?vhe=Wikisource_Bereshit_Rabbah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en Rabbi Levi said: [Abraham said:] ‘“Shall the Judge of all the earth not practice justice?” If You wish to have a world, there can be no strict justice, and if You wish to have strict justice, there can be no world. You seek to hold the rope from both ends; You wish to have the world and You wish to have strict justice. If You do not concede somewhat, the world will be unable to endure.’

The word מוותר is used in Mishneh Torah 5:13 https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.5.13?vhe=Wikisource_Mishneh_Torah&lang=bi A Torah Sage [should conduct] his business dealings with honesty and good faith. When [his] answer is "no," he says, "no;" when [his answer] is "yes," he says, "yes."
He is stringent with himself in his accounting, gives and yields to others when he buys from them, but is not demanding [about what they owe him].

@shmosel do something lo lishma and eventually you will do it lishma. When one is "giving in" begrudingly, it's because one isn't quite there yet in considering pleasing one's fellow more delightful than pleasing oneself, but eventually, one will come to enjoy doing things to please them, even in times when one has to let go of one's own preference. The story of the couple on the plane, where each was sitting in the seat they didn't prefer, because they thought the other wanted the one they also wanted comes to mind. I don't think either of them did it "begrudgingly" :)
